# Signature of Generated operator=()?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I have the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct S {
    const std::string str;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<S> v;
    const std::string test("test");
    S s;
    v.push_back(s);
}
```

It compiles fine with g++ 4.8.5:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

But when I tried to compile it with g++ 4.6.2, I got the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/vector:70:0,
                 from compilerTest.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/vector.tcc: In member function ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const S&}, _Tp = S, _Alloc = std::allocator<S>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<S*, std::vector<S> >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer = S*]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_vector.h:834:4:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = S, _Alloc = std::allocator<S>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = S]’
compilerTest.cpp:12:14:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/vector.tcc:319:4: error: use of deleted function ‘S& S::operator=(const S&)’
compilerTest.cpp:4:8: error: ‘S& S::operator=(const S&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
compilerTest.cpp:4:8: error: passing ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/char_traits.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/string:42,
                 from compilerTest.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_algobase.h: In static member function ‘static _BI2 std::__copy_move_backward<true, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_move_b(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = S*, _BI2 = S*]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:581:18:   instantiated from ‘_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with bool _IsMove = true, _BI1 = S*, _BI2 = S*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:590:34:   instantiated from ‘_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a2(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with bool _IsMove = true, _BI1 = S*, _BI2 = S*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:661:15:   instantiated from ‘_BI2 std::move_backward(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = S*, _BI2 = S*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/vector.tcc:313:4:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {const S&}, _Tp = S, _Alloc = std::allocator<S>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<S*, std::vector<S> >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer = S*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_vector.h:834:4:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = S, _Alloc = std::allocator<S>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = S]’
compilerTest.cpp:12:14:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:546:6: error: use of deleted function ‘S& S::operator=(const S&)’
```

Why `S& S::operator=(const S&)` is "deleted"?

I was using the command to compile:

```
g++ -Wall compilerTest.cpp -o compilerTest -std=c++0x
```

Even I uses emplace_back(), it gives me similar error:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++allocator.h:34:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/allocator.h:48,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/string:43,
                 from compilerTest.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/ext/new_allocator.h: In member function ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::basic_string<char>&}, _Tp = S, __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = S*]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/vector.tcc:97:6:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::basic_string<char>&}, _Tp = S, _Alloc = std::allocator<S>]’
compilerTest.cpp:11:18:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/ext/new_allocator.h:114:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘S::S(std::basic_string<char>&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/ext/new_allocator.h:114:4: note: candidates are:
compilerTest.cpp:4:8: note: S::S()
compilerTest.cpp:4:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
compilerTest.cpp:4:8: note: S::S(const S&)
compilerTest.cpp:4:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const S&’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/vector:70:0,
                 from compilerTest.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/vector.tcc: In member function ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::basic_string<char>&}, _Tp = S, _Alloc = std::allocator<S>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<S*, std::vector<S> >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer = S*]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/vector.tcc:102:4:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::basic_string<char>&}, _Tp = S, _Alloc = std::allocator<S>]’
compilerTest.cpp:11:18:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/vector.tcc:319:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘S::S(std::basic_string<char>&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/vector.tcc:319:4: note: candidates are:
compilerTest.cpp:4:8: note: S::S()
compilerTest.cpp:4:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
compilerTest.cpp:4:8: note: S::S(const S&)
compilerTest.cpp:4:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const S&’
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/char_traits.h:41:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/string:42,
                 from compilerTest.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_algobase.h: In static member function ‘static _BI2 std::__copy_move_backward<true, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_move_b(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = S*, _BI2 = S*]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:581:18:   instantiated from ‘_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with bool _IsMove = true, _BI1 = S*, _BI2 = S*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:590:34:   instantiated from ‘_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a2(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with bool _IsMove = true, _BI1 = S*, _BI2 = S*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:661:15:   instantiated from ‘_BI2 std::move_backward(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = S*, _BI2 = S*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/vector.tcc:313:4:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::basic_string<char>&}, _Tp = S, _Alloc = std::allocator<S>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<S*, std::vector<S> >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer = S*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/vector.tcc:102:4:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::basic_string<char>&}, _Tp = S, _Alloc = std::allocator<S>]’
compilerTest.cpp:11:18:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:546:6: error: use of deleted function ‘S& S::operator=(const S&)’
compilerTest.cpp:4:8: error: ‘S& S::operator=(const S&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
compilerTest.cpp:4:8: error: passing ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Very interesting that push_back uses copy assignment, try emplace_back()

Comment: @gbehar same error.  I think it is known that push_back() will call assignment operator because std containers make a copy when an element is inserted.

Comment: Actually, you have an implicit copy constructor, and in c++11 that's what push_back uses. I guess even with -std=c++0x there is no full support of this. in c++03 both copy constructor and copy assignment are required for vector items. In your case the copy assignment is deleted

Comment: Right, my question in this post is trying to find out why assignment operator is deleted.

Comment: Well, that is because you have a const member

Comment: I thought the assignment operator would be generated with const as well.  At least in gcc 4.8.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why S& S::operator=(const S&) is "deleted"?

Because `S` has a `const` member `str` which makes the defaulted copy assignment operator is defined as [deleted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator).

> A defaulted copy assignment operator for class `T` is defined as deleted if any of the following is true:
>
> `T` has a non-static data member or a direct or virtual base class that cannot be copy-assigned (overload resolution for the copy assignment fails, or selects a deleted or inaccessible function);

It's impossible to call `operator=` on a `const string`, it's a non-const member function.

And the type requirements of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) changed from C++11:

> `T` must meet the requirements of CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible.
>     (until C++11)
>
> The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual
>   operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that
>   element type is a complete type and meets the requirements of
>   Erasable, but many member functions impose stricter requirements.
>     (since C++11)

So from C++11 the requirment depends on the operation you performed. In fact, [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) doesn't need type `T` to be [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable), [CopyInsertable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyInsertable) would be fine.

> Type requirements
>   - T must meet the requirements of CopyInsertable in order to use overload (1).

That's why it compiles with gcc4.8.5, but gcc4.6.2 complains the copy assignment operator is deleted. (AFAIK gcc supported C++11 from 4.8.1)

Comment: Very detailed answer.  I just wonder whether there are more verbose description on CopyInsertable?  The link you included provides a formal description on what it means.  But a bit hard to see what "std::allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v);" is well-formed means in words (besides the expression can be compiled without errors).  Thanks.

Comment: @Hei The point is (also written at the beginning) "can be copy-constructed". And for your case, it will be (also written at the end) "as by ::new((void*)p) T(v)". `S` has a const member then can't be copy assigned by `operator=()`, but it can be copy constructed by its copy constructor. That's the difference.

Comment: I see your point that a const member can't be copy assigned by operator=().  Would you mind giving me an example of something that can't be copy-constructed?  (I know this is slightly deviated from the original post; hope you don't mind)  Thanks.

Comment: @Hei Sure. You can make the copy constructor `delete` explicitly by writing `S(const S&) = delete;`, or make `S` having a member which can't be copy constructed, such as `std::unique_ptr<int> p;`.

Comment: Argh, so the fancy term "copy constructible" just means a class has a copy constructor?

Comment: @Hei Yes, in most case. And `copy assignable` means an available `operator=`. But they're still not the same thing, it's not related to type `T` only, also the container and its allocator. The strict definition is shown as the link I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Copy assignment is implicitly deleted when you have a non static const member

That's because the object that you copy into is not re-initialized, so you have an existing const that you can't reassign into.

In your case there's not full support of C++11, which requires vector members to have copy assignment